# Multiplying two dropdown values results in NaN with one value

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have a simple function that monitors for '**change**' in two dropdown fields, then multiplies both values to display the sum total which is updated live while using the form.
2. Using bootstrap selectpicker -- there is no default selection, and therefore no value before a selection is made in the dropdown field.
3. When the first of dropdown selections is made, the change is detected and the value is multiplied against a non-value. Thus resulting in a NaN output.

**How can I output the total only after both dropdown fields are selected?**

**[JSFiddle example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/cvpbnjeo/1/)**

```
<label>Group Size</label>
<select class="selectpicker group calculate" id="group" name="group" data-rule-required="true" title="Choose Group Size...">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<label>Price</label>
<select class="selectpicker price calculate" id="price" name="price" data-rule-required="true" title="Choose Price...">
<option value="10">Option A: $10</option>
<option value="20">Option B: $20</option>
<option value="30">Option B: $30</option>
</select>

<label>Total Sum:</label>
<input name='total' id='total' disabled='true' data='' />

$('.calculate').change(function(){
    var group = parseInt($('.selectpicker.group').val());
    var price = parseInt($('.selectpicker.price').val());
    var total = group * price;
    $('#total').val('$' + total);
});
```

*The NaN Error:*

[image: NaN Error]

Comment: `if(!(isNaN(total))){$('#total').val('$' + total)};`

Comment: woops forgot about that thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an if/else statement with `isNaN()`:

```
if(isNaN(total)){
  $('#total').val('');
} else{
  $('#total').val('$' + total);
}
```

It might be tempting to just use an `if()` statement, but if you later use `<option></option>` it will cause unexpected results. It's better to empty the input using `else` if the value is not a number.

Answer (score 3):

Just check if your value are selected or if they are a number

```
if(isNaN(total)==false )
{
    $('#total').val('$' + total);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cvpbnjeo/2/)

Comment: Note without an `else` the value is not reset to null. For instance, if you later have `<option></option>` and the user selects it.

Comment: @rybo111 That's true but in his example he have no empty option

Comment: It's a basic example to resolve the problem, though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.calculate').change(function(){
    var groupstr = $('.selectpicker.group').val();
    var pricestr = $('.selectpicker.price').val();
    if (!isNaN(groupstr) && !isNaN(pricestr)) {
        var group = parseInt(groupstr);
        var price = parseInt(pricestr);
        var total = group * price;
        $('#total').val('$' + total);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

write your javascript as

```
    $('.calculate').change(function(){
    var group = parseInt($('.selectpicker.group').val());
   var price = parseInt($('.selectpicker.price').val());
   var total = group * price;
   //Check if total is not a number
   if(!isNaN(total)) {
  $('#total').val('$' + total);
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because when you change first dropdown of group then value of second dropdown gives NaN value that is why you are getting NaN as a result. you should keep a validation if both the dropdown gets selected then you multiply it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a select list. You need to access select list as a select list.

```
$('.calculate').change(function(){
    var selectgroup = $('.selectpicker.group').get(0);
    var selectprice = $('.selectpicker.price').get(0);

    var total = parseInt(selectgroup.options[selectgroup.selectedIndex].value) * parseInt(selectprice.options[selectprice.selectedIndex].value);
    $('#total').val('$' + total);
});
```

It totally beats my why jQuery doesn't pick up on select types to get it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('.calculate').change(function () {
    if (Number($('.selectpicker.group').val()) && Number($('.selectpicker.price').val())) {
        var total = Number($('.selectpicker.group').val()) * Number($('.selectpicker.price').val());
        $('#total').val('$' + total);
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ynedej6n/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate both:

```
$('.calculate').change(function(){
    var group = parseInt($('.selectpicker.group').val());
    var price = parseInt($('.selectpicker.price').val());
    if(group && price) {
        var total = group * price;
        $('#total').val('$' + total);
    }
});
```